"Four or six times", where is five?
This question arose from the reading of (a Spanish edition) of The First Voyage around the World (1519-1522): An Account of Magellan's Expedition by Pigafetta, where at some point he writes "they took the same spear four or six times".
I found it weird but attributed it to either medieval spanish/italian translation issues or to "corruption" of the original text. But then I found something very similar (skipping one number when mentioning an action that is repeated some number of times) when reading Memorias póstumas de Blas Cubas by Machado de Assis.
What is the reason behind this? Are such constructions ("x / x+2 times") actually quite common?
Thanks in advance!

This isn't really a literary question, but a language one. It's very common in ordinary speech where I'm from, for example.

I’m voting to close this question because to quote @cmw, "This isn't really a literary question, but a language one" – plus, the 2nd part of the question is unanswerable (we don't know what the OP "originally thought"), invites opinion (grounds for closure) & requests a list (grounds for closure).

I voted to close as there may be many equally valid answers depending on the language used as an example and the reasoning may be different for each. Maybe this is common in Romantic languages but not Germanic ones (to make up an example).  I think if you narrow this down to one language, it is perfectly fine, but that needs to be stated/clarified (e.g., is this common in English; which given the answer it appears that it is).

This is an ordinary form of words in English, as well as in the other languages noted in the question, where “M or N” (with M and N numbers) means “from M to N, approximately”:

or conj. 4.b. Used between numeral adjectives to convey an approximate quantity, as four or five, forty or fifty, etc.
Oxford English Dictionary.

Examples with a gap of two, as in the passage quoted in the question, are easy to come by:

1745   Columella Concerning Trees 598   After the space of three or five years, when it has had a large-enough growth, bend down that branch of the olive-tree that shall appear to be the goodliest.
1714   Henry Maundrell A Journey from Aleppo to Jerusalem 71   Thus they spend their time, many of them for four or six years together
1700   Daniel Whitby A Paraphrase and Commentary on the New Testament 380    when St Paul came to Rome, about five or seven years after
1914   Adam Shortt Canada and its Provinces X 490   Nearly all these were constructed of green timber, and consequently lasted only six or eight years at most.
1833   F. R. Chesney Reports on the Navigation of the Euphrates 27   the route of Egypt is seven or nine days quicker from Bombay to the Mediterranean
1842   John Sproule A Treatise on Agriculture 391   In warm weather, eight or ten days will sometimes be sufficient, and, in other cases, ten or twelve, or even longer, may be required.

In these examples it should be clear that an approximate range of values is meant.

In short, in more contemporary English, the tendency would be to write four to six rather than four or six. The implicit meaning tends to be clearer with a phrase like “40 or 50 feral hogs”¹ where the listener is accustomed to accept any value within that range (and maybe even a little outside it), but less so with non order-of-magnitude gaps.


I’m aware that the original quote was “30 to 50 feral hogs” but I couldn’t resist.


@D.A.Hosek the "non order-of-magnitude gaps" thing is hard to pin down exactly but often indicates deliberate humor. "5 or 6" is serious, "5 or 10" is serious, "5 or 11" is someone pulling your leg.
